# List matching files into an array

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to make a script that lists the available versions of a file, like this:

```
/home/test/file1.0
/home/test/file1.1
/home/test/file2.0
/home/test/file2.1
...
/home/test/file2.14
```

What I'd need is an array containing all of the values: `1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, ..., 2.14`. Now I came up to this:

```
VERSIONS=$(ls /home/test/file* | egrep '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | cut -c 16-);
```

Which somehow works, but the result is a string like this

```
1.0 1.1 2.0 2.1 ... 2.14
```

I'd need an array though. How can I have the result as array of values, instead of a single string?

Comment: Because you assign to a string, you assign arrays via arr = (el1 el2 el3), enclose the right side of your assignment with VERSIONS in brackets and you will get an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an array.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

versions=(/home/test/file*)

printf '%s\n' "${versions[@]##*+([[:alpha:]])}"
```

- Needs an `extglob` bash shell option.

To save to save that output.

```sh
array=("${versions[@]##*+([[:alpha:]])}")
```

Your version can be done with something like

```
versions=(/home/test/file*)

mapfile -t array < <(printf '%s\n' "${versions[@]}" | egrep '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | cut -c 16-)
```

Now `"${array[@]}"` has the values that you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ls`. Use a wildcard to populate the array, then use parameter expansion to remove the prefix from all the elements of the array:

```
files=( file* )
versions=( "${files[@]#file}" )
```